# Insert pictures randomly into a video

Tags: video-editor, photos

I have a lot of pictures, which I want to randomly insert all of them into a movie.

- I have a mac but also can use windows if needed. don't have any software for it yet and of course prefer a free software but if not possible I don't mind to buy a software for it. Thanks
- Background: It's my partner's birthday and I would like to project her photos inserted randomly (doesn't matter where in the movie) into the movie which is related to the party theme.

Comment: What do you mean by 'insert'? Do you want a slideshow where you see one of the images at a time filling the entire screen? Or some kind of collage? And how many images are we talking about, 100 or 10.000?

Comment: I don't quite understand if you want a macro / script which randomly distributes photos over a timeline before you render out a movie or do you want this to happen in realtime? If the latter is the case probably you want to look at software aimed towards Vjs, Here is a thread discussing free vj tools: http://vjforums.info/threads/is-there-any-free-vj-software.30990/

Comment: @MoritzLost Number of pictures is around 250 and the length of the movie is 120 minutes. the entire screen will be fine also collage or any effects. Just adding 250 photos one by one can be quite time consuming and that's why I'm hoping there is an easier way!

Comment: @HansMeiser Sorry if the question is not clear. I don't need a script or anything like that. Just want to have these images in the movie (fullscreen or some random effects). Adding 250 pictures one by one can be a bit time consuming hence I'm asking if there's any easy way. Thanks

Comment: Ah OK, so something like the thing that is strangely referred to as the "Ken burns" effect - strange because I think he is pretty unknown in Europe. There is a 3rd party preset for after effects, if you got that as well: http://www.proloststore.com/products/burns  alternative you can animate a couple of images yourself in premiere, save those animations on keyframes and drop it on the image sequence you created from your photos.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HITFILM EXPRESS. Its absolutely free non-linear editor.
Get Hitfilm Express here : https://hitfilm.com/express

You can drop a sequence of images at once. For this you can refer this YouTube tutorial :

Then you can apply some transitions between the pictures and add a music track to complete the video. 
Tutorial on how to apply transitions in Hitfilm Express :

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MAC you can use the following basic software:
iPhoto - create an ALBUM containing the pictures you want to insert into the video.
iMovie - Import the video you want to use in the project as the main storyline (In the left sidebar click "Photos Library" to access your photos, click the photo, move the playhead in the main storyline to where you want to insert the photo THEN:
press "Q" (connect edit) to connect the picture above the storyline (you have options to set the picture as split screen, cutaway, or picture in picture) OR
press "W" (insert edit) to insert the picture in the storyline (you can set transitions between the inserted pictures).

(ripple training.com has a training video on iMovie basics that is great)